# How ffmpeg can return wavespic png image to console in png

Tags: ffmpeg

This command return wavespic in stdout.

```
ffmpeg -i "/home/01.mp3" -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand,showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 -f  image2 -
```

I want return to stdout wavespic in png format. But i cant choose format in this case `-f  image2 -`. Yes i can do `-f  output.png` but i dont want save file to disk.

Comment: What do you mean by "palette color"?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  indexed color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i "/home/01.mp3" -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand,showwavespic=s=640x120" -c:v png -frames:v 1 -f  image2 -
```

If you need indexed colors, add `-pix_fmt pal8`